# Establishing a Sequence of Asynchronous Events in a Google Earth Engine App

Tags: google-earth-engine, user-interface, weighted-overlay, async

I am currently writing a tool in Google Earth Engine that is comparable to ESRI's [Weighted Overlay](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/weighted-overlay.htm)

As of now, the user can interactively reclassify and weight each raster layer. Ultimately they will be able to apply the layer parameters and produce a spatial output in the map panel.

I would like to add some additional functionality that will require the use of [asynchronous events](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ui_events#asynchronous-events).

Using the checkboxes (no current functionality) in the [app](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a7e74c1e86432637eaa52bdaeae37eb9), I would like users to be able to select layers that will be used for the weighted overlay. However, this layer selection would have to somehow get pushed to the other sections of the app.

In this example below I am pushing the checkbox selection to a list, but I am not sure how to continuously embed/update that list in another widget

```
var input_list = []

// CHECKBOX WIDGET SECTION
var Check1 = ui.Checkbox({
  label: 'Upland Species',
  value: false,
  onChange: function(checked) {
    if (checked) {
    input_list.push('Upland Species')
    }
    else {
    input_list = []
    }
  print(input_list)
  }
})
```

The selected layers would also have to be pushed into the last section, where weights are summed and the final output is calculated. So if I wanted to add the checkbox functionality into this application, I will have to establish a sequence of asynchronous events.

Would anyone know how to accomplish this?

[Link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a7e74c1e86432637eaa52bdaeae37eb9)

Comment: This question asked for something similar. Maybe it helps you? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411831/creating-multiple-dropdown-lists-in-gee-based-on-user-selection/411922#411922

Comment: I wasn't sure if I could somehow link checkbox widgets to a select widget.. it looks like I will have to just use select widgets